# It only displays one message rather choosing correct message to display

Tags: php

I am trying to determine questions answered correctly and questions answered incorrectly. If answered correctly then display "Fully Correct" else if incorrect then display the "Incorrect" message. Problem is no matter if correct or not it always displays that question is answered incorrectly.

Below is code:

```
    $check = true;

    foreach ($studentData['questions'] as $questionId => $questionData) {

            if($questionData['answer'] == $questionData['studentanswer'])
    {
        echo '<td width="30%" class="studentanswer green"><strong>'.htmlspecialchars($questionData['studentanswer']).'</strong></td>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<td width="30%" class="studentanswer red"><strong>'.htmlspecialchars($questionData['studentanswer']).'</strong></td>' . PHP_EOL;
        $check = false;
    }


if($check)
{
    echo '<p class="green"><strong>Fully Correct</strong></p>';
}
else
{
    echo '<p class="red"><strong>Not Correct / Not Fully Correct</strong></p>';
}

}
```

Comment: Define your `$check = true;` inside your foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after this line again set to `true` for `$check`

```
if($questionData['answer'] == $questionData['studentanswer'])
{
echo '<td width="30%" class="studentanswer green"><strong>'.htmlspecialchars($questionData['studentanswer']).'</strong></td>' . PHP_EOL;
$check = true;
} else
```

Comment: Oh, thought because I declared it on top that I thought I did not need to do this. Do I still need the $check above the foreach loop or remove it?

Comment: @Manixman don't remove it on top of `foreach`, but also set inside `if` condition to `true`.